# Connect to python-memcached using memcached.sock path

Tags: python, memcached, python-memcached

How do I connect to Python-memcached using the path to memcached.sock? (Python 2.7)

Memcached comes pre-installed on my host (Webfaction). I have started it and verified that it is running. I also verified that memcached.sock is in my home directory. The documentation says:

> "Once your Memcached instance is up and running, you can access it by
>   the path of the socket file (~/memcached.sock) with the software or
>   library which uses memcached."

I have tried this:

```
import memcache
mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=1)
mc.set("some_key", "Some value")
```

But I get an error on mc.set:

```
Connection refused.  Marking dead.
```

I have also tried

```
mc = memcache.Client('~/memcached.sock', debug=1)
```

Then the error on mc.set is

```
Name or service not known.  Marking dead.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working by doing this:

The setup:

```
memcached -d -s /tmp/memcached.sock
```

The code:

```
import memcache
mc = memcache.Client(['unix:/tmp/memcached.sock'], debug=0)
mc.set('hello', 'world')
print(mc.get('hello'))
```

The full test:

```
docker run --rm -t python:3.6 bash -c "$(cat << 'EOF'
# setup
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y memcached && \

# start memcached
memcached -u nobody -d -s /tmp/memcached.sock && \

# install the requirements
pip install python-memcached && \

# run the code
python <(cat << FOE
import memcache
mc = memcache.Client(['unix:/tmp/memcached.sock'], debug=0)
mc.set('hello', 'world')
print(mc.get('hello'))
FOE
)

EOF
)"
```

... spoilers, it prints out `"world"`